# Using project on point shape file to change coordinate system using ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, error-999999, arcgis-10.8

I have created a model using ModelBuilder in ArcMap 10.8 to do the following:

1. Project point shape file to change coordinate system from A to B
2. Add a field (X)
3. Calculate field: `!SHAPE.CENTROID.X!` using python_9.3
4. Add a field (Y)
5. Calculate field: `!SHAPE.CENTROID.Y!` using python_9.3
6. Table to excel.

Whenever I run the model it stops at "Project" and gives me the following error `ERROR 999999: Error executing function`. Create output feature class failed Failed to execute (Project)."

Why does it not work? When I do this manually it works.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried deleting Project and adding it again to your model?

Comment: That worked for some weird reason. However, now the model stops at "Add field" where I get the following message "ERROR 000229: Cannot open L:\XXXX
Failed to execute (Add Field).

Comment: I suspect its some sort of file locking issue, your drive is L:\ , why not write to `C:\temp` see if that fixes it?